# Forget Android Screen Lock Pin for samsung galaxy s7262

Tags: samsung

Forget Android Screen Lock Pin for samsung galaxy s7262
tried many times not even asking for forget pin or google account details.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these instructions:

1. [Root your mobile](http://androidxda.com/root-samsung-galaxy-star-pro-duos-gt-s7262)
2. Using ADB delete the file under `/data/system/gesture.key` for Gesture or `/data/system/passwd.key` for Password/PIN.
3. Reboot your mobile
4. If you were using a PIN ,it won't ask anything. You can directly start using your mobile.

Don't worry about your data as it won't be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Try entering the lock pin for several times, the Google password recovery will popup and will ask you for recovery options.

**If the above recovery fails, nothing else will work.**

Just go and reset you phone.

Here is a good tutorial for hard resetting your device.

[Tutorial for hard reset a Samsung device](http://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-s7262-galaxy-star-pro/)

Comment: V_J, you accepted an inappropriate [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/117172). Was approving it a mistake or a careful calculated attempt? See [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155539) (*for Suggested Edits*)

Comment: I accidently approved the edit. Apologies @Firelord.